# Turborepo styles

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, monorepo, turborepo

When I want to use the following `Button` component I need to add the stylesheet of that package in the app.

packages/
ui/
src/
button/
Button.tsx

apps/
todo/
src/
app/
page.tsx

```
import "ui/styles.css";
```

Is it possible to import the component without importing the stylesheet?!

Comment: Why don't you import it once in the layout?

Comment: It conflicts with other styles